# How do I make an embed code for other to share on their website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, embed

I made a tool last week and I have had a bunch of requests for an embed code. People want to simply drop an code onto their page so my tool shows up on their website/blog.

I know of a few options but I am unsure what is the quickest and easiest way, iframe? embed? a div and a script to load the page inside?

The reason I'm so concern with responsiveness is because my tool has two side by side divs each taking half width, then when small enough it drops down to one above the other each taking full width.

What is the best way to do this?
Can an iFrame be responsive?
Are Embed fully supported?
Is a div and script too much to ask?

Comment: iFrame is quickest and easiest.

Comment: @Zealander but what about responsive? don't you give a solid px value for height and width? how would I make it responsive with an iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for an iFrame, if the content has something like an aspect ratio. This responsive example has an 16:9 aspect ratio. Tweak the `padding-bottom` to change height:

```
<div style='position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%;'>
    <iframe style="border:none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src='https://charts.datawrapper.de/bTcko/' style='border:0'></iframe>
</div>
```

If there is no aspect ratio, you could use a script that controls the responsiveness of the container, which can also be an iFrame:

```
<iframe id="datawrapper-chart-bTcko" src="https://charts.datawrapper.de/bTcko/" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" width="100%" height="100"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var aspectRatio = [4, 3],
        chart = document.getElementById('datawrapper-chart-bTcko');

    chart.style.height = chart.offsetWidth / aspectRatio[0] * aspectRatio[1] + 'px';
</script>
```

You could also use the script to load the content via AJAX, if the correct CORS headers are set (security reasons).

Personally I'd always go with the first solution, if possible. Many people don't like to embed something that says `<script>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The reason I'm so concern with responsiveness is because my tool has two side by side divs each taking 50%, then when small enough it drops down to one above the other. Could I achieve this with an iframe still like your suggested?

Comment: Yes, it would. If it works when your are resizing your browser window it would also work when the iFrame gets resized.

Comment: Whats the reason for the padding bottom? Im not sure people who use the embed would want massive white space below the embed.

Comment: Have you tried it out? There will be no giant whitespace. This is a common CSS trick to achieve aspect preserving responsive embeds: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Oh thanks, I was trying out in codepen. I will test this more. :D

Comment: Sorry, I posted it to the wrong thread. But seriously, just paste your tool's URL in the embed code and try it out.

Comment: I have been testing this today and it always adds a scroll bar, as if its overflow:scroll (which it isnt) any ideas?